# Exclusive dashboard is not showing reports in Sitecore when register local search using DMS

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I am working on register local search terms in Sitecore DMS. I took help from the following [blog](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/register-local-search-terms-in-sitecore-dms/).  First of all I registered a Search page Event with named "Search".

```cs
protected void RegisterSearchPageEvent(string searchQuery)
{
    if (!Tracker.IsActive || Tracker.Visitor == null || Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit == null)
        return;

    var page = Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit.CurrentPage;
    if (Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit.PreviousPage != null)
        page = Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit.PreviousPage;

    page.Register(new PageEventData("Search")
    {
        Data = searchQuery,
        DataKey = searchQuery.ToLowerInvariant(),
        Text = searchQuery
    });
}
```

I also defined the page event “Search” in Sitecore. Now to display the Report in `Executive Dashboard` I went under the "Site Search" but it does not display anything.
I configured the .config file located here:

```
\sitecore\shell\Applications\Reports\Dashboard\Configuration.config
```

Here there is a setting called “MinimumVisitsFilter“. I set it from 50 to 5 and also entered the search keywords - more than 50 times. The main point is here is that the above code is inserting the keyword into the Analytics database. Is there any SQL Query problem for `Executive Dashboard`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above problem is due to browser cache. Sitecore DMS Search event stores the single value for one word if we don't close the browser or need to search from the different browser to store the value. If this kind of problem occurs, then search for different keywords by closing the browser and then clearing the cache. This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Even with the MinimumVisitsFilter set to 5, you still need to generate 5 unique visits to start seeing any data. On your local dev environment you could probably set this one as low as 1 or even 0 - but I would not recommend you did this on the live environment.

Also make sure all the basics are in place; Analytics is active (Sitecore.Analytics.config), the database is set up and so on.

I followed the same post when registering local search, and the procedure Brian describes here does work.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I already generate 5 unique visits it also store value into DMS database, i manually check for it. The problem is only with "Executive DashBoard". It doesn't showing any report, there is only "no statistically significant data available for the selected time range" message is shown even when i select the whole time range